# XQuery to get a list of all attributes an element has

Tags: xml, xpath, generics, xquery

Is there a generic way of determining all attributes (and their values) from an XML node using XQuery/XPath?

```
<parent>
   <something attr1="123" attrA="abc" ..... attrAnythingelse="blablabla"/>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get all attributes for the current node using XPath:

```
@*
```

Is that what you're after?

The names and values of the attributes can be extracted per attribute:

```
name(@*[1])
string(@*[1])
```

Depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: yeah that's for the values, and i also need the attributenames

Comment: You'll need to iterate through the attribute nodes returned by this. There's no way that I'm aware of to write one xpath query that will return a list of key value pairs for the attributes of an element node. (This answer returns a nodeset of attribute nodes, the node name is available with another xpath query)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
return for $att in $doc//@*
    return (fn:concat(name($att),"=","'",$att,"'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

$doc//@*/(concat(name(.),"=",.))

Answer (score 0):

Get all attributes with their values using XQuery:

```
for $attr in //@*
return concat(name($attr), " = &quot;", $attr, "&quot;&#10;")
```